# Next 13+ check mobile device

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, jsx

Next js ile proje geliştiriyorum. burada eğer mobile cihaz ise bir component render etmek istiyorum. ama bu isMobileDevice değerini jsx içerisinde kullanırsam aşadıdaki hataları alıyorum.

```
import useTranslation from "next-translate/useTranslation";
import isMobile from "ismobilejs";
import DefaultLayout from "../../components/core/Layouts/Default";
import { MouseIcon, ScrollDownWrapper, ScrollText, SearchBoxWrapper, SliderWrapper, Wrapper } from "./style";
import MainSlider from "../../components/common/MainSlider";
import SearchBox from "../../components/common/SearchBox";

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation("home");
    const isMobileDevice = isMobile()?.any;

    return (
        <DefaultLayout>
            <Wrapper>
                <SearchBoxWrapper>
                    <SearchBox />
                    {isMobileDevice && (
                        <ScrollDownWrapper>
                            <MouseIcon />
                            <ScrollText>{t("scrollDown")}</ScrollText>
                        </ScrollDownWrapper>
                    )}
                </SearchBoxWrapper>
                <SliderWrapper>
                    <MainSlider />
                </SliderWrapper>
            </Wrapper>
        </DefaultLayout>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

[image]

I want to render the project on client side using "use client" because isMobijeJs needs window object but it doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [react-device-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect) package. which is also fairly easy to use and has great options like spesific view elemets which addresses your issue. I've tested this on Next 13.2 and can confirm that it works.